# Search Tags acts_as_taggable_on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search, tags

I have created an app where advertising banners can be saved to a database and tagged with attributes, for example the dimensions of the banner (for example 300x250).

This has all been done using `acts_as_taggable_on`.

Now what I want to do is have a search box that when the user types in the dimension (for example 300x250) then my page will filter to show only the advertising banners tagged with '300x250' (this doesn't need to be done with Ajax or anything yet, a search button is fine)

I have currently installed the gem Ransack to search but can't figure out how to integrate it with `Acts_as_taggable_on`.

Is there an easy way for me to have a search box in my view that will search just through the tags and update the page with only the tagged objects?

Thanks so much in advance for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0):

That's easy. We just should write correct associations for ransack.

`reflect_on_all_associations` or `reflections` shows that `Banner` has an association named `:taggable`, which leads to model ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging, which `belongs_to` ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.

So then:

```
@q = Banner.ransack(taggings_tag_name_cont: 'interesting')
@banners = @q.result
```

Of course, be free using other matchers like `eq`, `in` and so on